# How can I hide too many variants using an expand button

Tags: javascript, css, magento, attributes, magento2

Since my Magento has many selection fields like 20 for some attributes like color, I only want to display 7 and have the rest expand using an expand button.

Is there this function in Magento or an extension that can do this task?

It should look something like this picture here.

Would you like to have a button like this, or does this function not exist? Does it have to be done with Java Script? If so, where and how?

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgJ4y.jpg)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vbqy.jpg)

Comment: That would be a custom coding situation. Depending on the structure of your page would determine how the JS and CSS would interact. But that depends on what your code currently looks like. Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What exactly do you need, I use Magento 2 with the Porto theme.  I would be happy about help.

Comment: Depends where that code is and how much access you have to it. I'm not sure specifically if Magento has anything to use, but if they don't you can probably shift it around on page load using Javascript / jQuery. I couldn't advise you how to do it without seeing, but this sounds like it'd be easier getting someone to do it for you on like upwork or fiverr or something.